# Append spark Dstream to a single file in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a program reading Kafka and printing output in spark. I need this output to be appended to a single file..
my code writes to a folder. which spark writes to multiple files and then I have another utility which will aggregate the results from files.

Is there any simple way to append data from multiple RDD's of DStream to the same file?
OR 
Can I combine all Dstream RDD's to one DStream and Stream/Append it to a file

```
    conf = SparkConf() \
         .setAppName("PySpark Cassandra Test") \
         .setMaster("spark://host:7077") \
         .set("spark.rpc.netty.dispatcher.numThreads","2")

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

    zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
    parsed = kvs.map(lambda (k, v): json.loads(v))
    mapped = parsed.map(lambda event: (event['test'], 1))
    reduced = mapped.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y)
    result = reduced.map(lambda x: {"test": x[0], "test2": x[1]})
    result.pprint()
    result.saveAsTextFiles("file:///test/hack")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

I could do it using foreachRDD

```
def tpprint(val, num=10):
    """
    Print the first num elements of each RDD generated in this DStream.
    @param num: the number of elements from the first will be printed.
    """
    def takeAndPrint(time, rdd):
        taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
        print("########################")
        print("Time: %s" % time)
        print("########################")
        for record in taken[:num]:
            print(record)
            with open("/home/ubuntu/spark-1.4.1/test.txt", "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(str(record))
        if len(taken) > num:
            print("...")
        print("")

    val.foreachRDD(takeAndPrint)
```

Call it like 
    result = reduced.map(lambda x: {"feddback_id": x[0], "pageviews": x[1]})

```
tpprint(result)
```